# VueJS: Watcher on a computed property never called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to watch a computed property to be able to change a data value.
The return of the `sortedCars` **computed property** is an array. 
The problem is that the `sortedCars` **watcher** is never called.

```
watch: {

        sortedCars: {
            handler: function (val, oldVal) {
                this.filterCarLabel = newVal[0];
            },
            deep: true
        }

},
computed: {

        sortedCars() {
            function compare(a, b) {
                if (i18n.t(a).toLowerCase() < i18n.t(b).toLowerCase()) return -1;
                if (i18n.t(a).toLowerCase() > i18n.t(b).toLowerCase()) return 1;

                return 0;
            }

            return this.cars.slice().sort(compare);
        }

}
```

Comment: Instead of setting up the watcher to store the first sorted car in the array as `filterCarLabel`, can't you simply use `sortedCars[0]` in your template? Also, if you want to do it your way, shouldn't it be `this.filterCarLabel = val[0];` instead? `newVal` is undefined.

Comment: Or make `filterCarLabel` a computed property? How are you determining that the `handler` isn't being called? Using console logging?